# Appending to a doubly linked list and displaying

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have two classes `Person` and `Node`. the following is what i have:

(Please note everything is in one cpp file i am just separating it for a better view.)

Header files

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

**Person Class**

```
class Person
{
    int age;
    string name;

    void setage(int age)
    {
        this->age = age;
    }

    void setname(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    int getage()
    {
        return this->age;
    }


    string getname()
    {
        return this->name;
    }
};
```

**Node Class**

```
class Node
{

public:
    Node * Next;
    Node * Prev;
    Person * Data;

    Node * Head;
    Node * Tail;


    Node()
    {
        Node * Head = NULL, *Tail = NULL;
    }


    void AppendNode(Node * pNode)
    {

        if (Head == NULL)
        {               //if list is empty
            Head = pNode;       //make head point to pNode
            pNode->Prev = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            Tail->Next = pNode; //make tail point to pNode
            pNode->Prev = Tail;
        }

        Tail = pNode;       //tail is now pNode
        pNode->Next = NULL;     //pNode next now points to NULL
    }


    void display(Node * pNode)
    {
        for (pNode = Head; pNode != NULL; pNode = pNode->Next)
            cout << pNode->Data << endl;
    }
};
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    Node * pNode;
    //Add items to linked list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pNode = new Node(); //allocate                                                    
        pNode->Data->setage(i);
        pNode->AppendNode(pNode);
    }
    pNode->display(pNode);

    /* for(pNode = pHead; pNode != NULL; pNode = pNode->pNext)
            cout<<pNode->nData<<endl; 
     */

    return 0;
}
```

I think I am doing it wrong but this is what I have.
I am append data into the list.
You can see the code here in a online compiler https://onlinegdb.com/Hk87R0UvS

the question is that i am not able to append to the list

Comment: What is the question/problem? Well, anyway, in you for loop, you are loosing your ponter reference at each interation.

Comment: @Amadeus i updated my question
"the question is that i am not able to append to the list"

Comment: The answer is at my previous comment. At each interaction of you for loop you are overwriting you pointer. You need to keep the first element of your list

Comment: @Amadeus i dont really understand what you mean

Comment: Looking just at the for loop, in main function: 1) first allocate a new Node; 2) initialize some data 3) apend it to itself, and repeat the loop. At this moment, you are loosing the address of the previous allocated node (you are overwrinte `*pNode`), restarting the process. In other words you have initialized your Node 10 times and lose 9 previous references. There is no linked nodes here

Answer (score 2):

Look at your definitions of `Head` and `Tail`. Actually there are several ones on your code.

First, you define both Head and Tail as (non-static) members. That means that these members are not shared between the nodes, and your list has multiple heads and multiple tails (whatever that could mean). Next, you redefine these variables inside of the constructor. You defile temporary variables and set them to NULL just to destroy them immediately.

So, make several modifications. First, make your Head and Tail members static to share them between nodes in the list (BTW that means that you plan to have just a single list in your program). Removing the temporary variables from the constructor is not needed, but would make your intention clear.

One more thing: you never construct the Person but you are trying to dereference the pointer.